# Does array name has memory allocated?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

If we declare an array in C inside a function like -
`int a[] = {1,2,3,4};`

There is a contiguous block of memory allocated in stack segment. Let us say at the address 1000.

```
1000
 |
 v
+--+--+--+--+
|1 |2 |3 |4 |
+--+--+--+--+
```

If we have a pointer `p` to integer -

```
int *p;
```

then we can assign either

```
p = &a[0];
```

OR

```
p = a;
```

The operator `p = &a[0];` is more self explanatory. ie a[0] is the 0th element in the (0 based) indexed array `a`. And `&a[0]` represents address of it and we are assigning that address to the integer pointer - `p`;

In the statement `p = a`, we are assigning the address of `a` to `p`. If we can assigned `a` to `p`, it should essential indicate that `a` (the array name) should be holding the address.
Does the variable `a` gets a separate memory allocated to store the starting address of the array? If so, in which segment of memory would it get stored?
If not, then how does the assignment statement `p=a` work?

Comment: `a` might be stored on the stack or in a general purpose register, or might be the current value of the stack register. Whether a given compiler choses to implement the assignment of the `p` variable by storing the same value in a slot on the stack, in a register, or by collapsing the alias and using the same slot or register that it uses for `a` depends on what it is going to do with 'p' next.  So the answer is 'maybe'.

Comment: There are only 4 words allocated for array `a`.  Names only exist in the source, not in the compiled code.

Comment: Technically, `p = a;` assigns the address of the initial element of `a` to `p`, not the address of `a` to `p`. The actual numeric memory addresses of `a` and the first element of `a` are the same, but the types of the pointer values are different. The identifier `a` denotes the array object itself (consisting of its elements) which needs to be stored. Its address is not an object that needs to be stored. Its address is a transient value used only within evaluation of any expression in which it is needed.

Comment: In other words, the compiler does not need to store the address of `a` in the same way that it does not need to store the result of any other expression such as `x + y`. It just needs to know how to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 2):

> In the statement `p = a`, we are assigning the address of a to p.

`&a[0]` is assigned, to be specific. `&a` and `&a[0]` produce pointers referencing the same address, but they have different types.

An array degrades into a pointer to its first element in nearly all circumstances, including this one. (Exceptions include `&a` and `sizeof(a)`.) This means that `p = a` is identical to `p = &a[0]` (by definition).

```c
int *p1      = &a[0];   // Pointer to the first element of the array.
int *p2      = a;       // Same.
int (*p3)[4] = &a;      // Pointer to an array of four `int` objects.
```

> it should essential indicate that `a` (the array name) should be holding the address.

Since `p = a` does the same thing as `p = &a[0]`, the former doesn't require any information that's not also needed for the latter.

> If not, then how does the assignment statement `p=a` work?

The compiler knows where the array is located (since it decides where to put it) and generates the appropriate code.

> Does the variable a gets a separate memory allocated to store the starting address of the array?

No. The address of the array is not stored in the array. That wouldn't be helpful, since you'd have to access the array to get the address, but you need the address to access the array.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, Fine, removed word

Answer (score 1):

> Does the variable `a` gets a separate memory allocated to store the starting address of the array?

No; instead, there is a special rule such that when an array expression appears in most contexts, it is *converted* to a pointer expression and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.

IOW, when the compiler sees something like

```
int *p = a;
```

it internally replaces that with something equivalent to

```
int *p = &a[0];
```

The exceptions to this rule occur when the array expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration.

This is done at compile time, not at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is named `a`. It stores four `int` elements contiguously in memory.

When you do:

```
int *p = a;
```

Then `a` decays to a pointer to its first element. The only new memory allocated is to store the pointer `p` which is likely either 4 or 8 bytes depending on compiler/platform. This is effectively no different from explicitly getting the address of the first element in the array with:

```
int *p = &a[0];
```

Further, at no point does `p` contain any information on the size of the array `a`.